# Pyramid periodic task with Celery

Tags: python, celery, pyramid

I'm try to use pyramid_celery. I managed to run simple tasks. But how with pyramid run of a periodic tasks? Where I need to write CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE?

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far?  In particular, could you add a [Short, Self-Contained, (Compilable) Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I used the standard example pyramid_celery_demo. But it does not show how tasks can be run periodically.

Comment: well, couldn't you just set a cron job to run a script that you write invoking pyramid_celery?

Comment: I need to schedule tasks to be queued for execution. Cron runs the job immediately. What can cause the job again twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Pyramid with Celery does not require using pyramid_celery module - the latter is just a thin integration layer which may or may not make your life easier. In your case it looks like it doesn't make your life easier, right?

Both Pyramid and Celery have excellent and very detailed documentation. `pyramid_celery` does not have detailed documentation. From my reading the code it looks like it reads celery configuration from paster .ini file (development.ini in case of pyramid_celery_demo app) - I have no idea how to stick a nested dict into an .ini file, but some commit messages suggest that it [somehow should work](https://github.com/sontek/pyramid_celery/commit/4aabd879356b8ca2dd204092dd3bd48c4d791640).

In short, your options are:

- read the code of `pyramid_celery` and figure out how it supposed to work
- write to the author of the package
- drop the package and use plain Pyramid and plain Celery, enjoying nice and clear documentation.

Further reading the code suggests that they 'eval()' string values read from the .ini file to convert them to python structures, so I'd assume putting something like

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = "{'key': 'value', 'another_key': 'another_value'}"
```

should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below section to your developement.ini file of project

```
[celerybeat:task1]
task = app1.tasks.Task1
type = crontab
schedule = {"minute": 0}
```

schedule is the format you need to write in cron style.Task1 is the task to be executed . Hope you got it. For more details visit this link. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_celery/